# mongodb which documents updated in bulk write

Tags: mongodb, resultset

I have a database with many documents.

I have a routine that updates new documents to this database daily.
I am specifying the _id value as I want each unique document to be added but not any duplicate documents.
Occasionally, I will run an update file through and some will be added, others will be matched and then every once in a while i will get one that was updated.

For speed, these are updated with a `bulkwrite` command.
I can get a count of each of these (Matched, Modified, Upserted, etc) from the results returned. However, I am looking to get a listing of the documents modified so they can be reviewed to understand why they weren't upserted.
Obviously, my key is not unique. However, the update program should always give unique keys for any documents changed. So I have both documents in the database.

I'm looking for a way to identify which matched and updated (ie. modified) so that we can verify what is happening.